# Read Data from .dbf File with OdbcConnection

Tags: c#, odbc, dbf

I am using visual studio 2010 on Win 7. I want to read a .dbf file and get the minimum value of a selected column.
Here is what I have:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + ImportDirPath + ";Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
oConn.Open();

// Update time
string nowTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
oCmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE " + tableName + " SET HQCJBS = " + nowTime + " WHERE HQZQDM = ?";
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("row2", "000000");
oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


string query = "SELECT MIN(" + colName + ") FROM " + tableName + " WHERE HQZQDM <> 000000";
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, oConn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Suppose `colName` and `tableName` are correct. I have two question.


**Two Questions**:
When the code `da.Fill(ds);` is hit, I got an error `data type mismatch in criteria expression access`, What is wrong?
After I get the minimum value from the database, how can I input it into the memory as a double, for example `double min = ds.Tables[0];`

Comment: It looks like 'HQZQDM' field is not of numeric type. This may cause the data type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update command should apply TWO parameters... one for the set, another for the where clause.  Use the "?" place-holder for each respectively and add the parameters in the same order as they appear in the query.

```
string nowTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
oCmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE " + tableName + " SET HQCJBS = ? WHERE HQZQDM = ?";
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setParm", nowTime );
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("whereParm, "000000");
oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For your select MIN() query, it appears your WHERE criteria column is a string and by having the literal numbers without quotes is applying it as a numeric... Again, stick with "?" parameters

```
OdbcCommand getMinCmd = new OdbcCommand("", oConn);
getMinCmd.CommandText = "SELECT MIN(" + colName 
       + ") FROM " + tableName + " WHERE HQZQDM <> ?";
getMinCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("whereParm, "000000");

OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(getMinCmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Finally, to get the value OUT of the retrieved query into memory, you need to get the row of the table (only 1 record result set, zero-based index) and column-0 too.  Since you did not assign a column name, you don't know the column and just go with 0-index...

```
int lowestValue = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
```

Think of the above as the hierarchy...

```
ds
  tables[0]
    rows[0]
      [column 0]
    rows[1]  -- but your query would only have one row anyhow
      [column 0]
  tables[1]  -- if your query had multiple queries, this might be available
```

but at least it shows where the pieces are.

Now, if you change your query slightly to something like

```
select MIN( colName ) as MyMinValue ...
```

then your reference would be where you explicitly name the column from the row retrieved

```
int lowestValue = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyMinValue"];
```